# windows clearcase: cleartool: Warning: Can not update license cache

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Following is the error while using ClearCase version 7.1.2.6 on windows site. Any suggestions how to fix it.

```
cleartool ls

cleartool: Warning: Can not update license cache 
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\var\cache\ClearCase_check\desker". 
Please check ownership or permission.
```

What could cause this error message?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [PM09741](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM09741):

#### Problem summary

> ClearCase licensing does not handle account user-ID changes without user name changes.

That means something has changed (like the license server name)

Comment: It happened only on one specific computer. There are many other computers that is sharing the same license server and haven't seen any problems like this.

Comment: @user2370590 is there anything else that has changed on that specific computer? A user login name? A user password?

Comment: Ran the clearcase doctor and didn't see any error. If the password was changed, atria licensing would have been stopped but in this case it is running. A user login handle is same as before.

Comment: @user2370590 and the issue persists after reboot, I presume?

Comment: yes, problem exists after rebooting as well. Re-installing again if it will fix the issue. I think domain was not specified during the first installation time. I will update you on it.